# Handling a custom taxonomy in WooCommerce wc_get_products function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I register a taxonomy using the standard action:

```
add_action( 'init', 'product_brand_order_taxonomy' );
function product_brand_order_taxonomy()  {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => 'Brand Heirarchy',
        'singular_name'              => 'Brand Heirarchy',
        'menu_name'                  => 'Brand Heirarchy',
        'all_items'                  => 'All Brand Heirarchies',
        'parent_item'                => 'Parent Brand Heirarchy',
        'parent_item_colon'          => 'Parent Brand Heirarchy:',
        'new_item_name'              => 'New Brand Heirarchy Name',
        'add_new_item'               => 'Add New Brand Heirarchy',
        'edit_item'                  => 'Edit Brand Heirarchy',
        'update_item'                => 'Update Brand Heirarchy',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate Brand Heirarchy with commas',
        'search_items'               => 'Search Brand Heirarchies',
        'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove Brand Heirarchies',
        'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used Brand Heirarchies',
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'brand_heirarchy', 'product', $args );
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'brand_heirarchy', 'product' );
}
```

Later I'd like to get products based on some arguments. I'd also like the `brand_heirarchy` to be included in the result.

```
$products = array(
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'limit' => -1,
    'category' => $parent_brand_slugs
);

$products = wc_get_products($product_args);
```

In the returned data it will give me `category_ids` like

```
[category_ids] => Array
    (
        [0] => 30
        [1] => 27
        [2] => 25
        [3] => 24
    )
```

But I would like to have it also return the ids of the `brand_heirarchy` that are associated with the products.

Most things I see is about how to filter products by a custom taxonomy, I just want to know what taxonomies are as associated with a product.

I ran across this saying Woocommerce doesn't allow this: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/13138

I looked at using this filter `woocommerce_product_object_query_args` but couldn't figure it out. There is also a product search filter, but it didn't look like it applied.

At this point, it seems my best bet is to loop over each product and use something like `wp_get_object_terms( $data['id'], 'brand_heirarchy' );` but that seems inefficient.

Been a long time since I've done Wordpress so really asking if there's a more efficient way I should be getting the taxonomies associated with each product.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is completely possible to handle a custom taxonomy using `wc_get_products()`. You didn't search in the right place as this is handled within [`WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT` class](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/7.9/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php) using the available [filter hook `woocommerce_product_data_store_cpt_get_products_query`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/7.9/plugins/woocommerce/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php#L2020).

So for your custom product taxonomy `brand_heirarchy`, you will use the following:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_store_cpt_get_products_query', 'handle_custom_query_var', 10, 2 );
function handle_custom_query_var( $query_args, $query_vars ) {
    if ( ! empty( $query_vars['brand'] ) ) {
        $query_args['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy'          => 'brand_heirarchy',
            'field'             => 'slug',
            'terms'             => $query_vars['brand'],
        );
    }
    return $query_args;
}
```

Then now you can use your custom taxonomy in `wc_get_products()` function like:

```php
$products = wc_get_products( array(
    'status' => 'publish',
    'limit' => -1,
    'brand' => $brand_slugs // array
) );
```

Now it should work.

---

Related documentation:

- [wc_get_products and WC_Product_Query](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query)
- [WP_Query Taxonomy Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters)